# 301 Redirect domain without www works, but with www does not

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Currently I'm working on a request to both redirect the domain A to domain B and redirect a specific page within the domain A to domain B.  Here's the expectation in pseudocode:

```
foo.com =====> https://www.bar.com
foo.com/foo =====> https://www.bar.com/bar
```

and:

```
www.foo.com =====> https://www.bar.com
www.foo.com/foo =====> https://www.bar.com/bar
```

However, only the non-www redirects are working as expected and the www redirects are not functioning at all.  Essentially, the first set of redirects above are working and the second set are not.

Here's my Vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias www.foo.com
    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/foo.com-error.log
  Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/rewrite_rules/foo.com.rewrite
</VirtualHost>
```

My rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo$  https://www.bar.com/bar  [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bar.com  [R=301,L,NC]
```

What's strange is when I test with curl on a test server, it seems as though the URL is being redirected:

```
301 http://www.foo.com/ https://www.bar.com
```

I get the feeling I'm missing something in my rewrite rule.  Can anyone advise on the problem?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to this issue.  As it turns out, the rules in place are all functional and work as intended; however, the SSL certificate on the server was causing a mismatch error.

This mismatch in SSL certificates stopped the redirect functionality.  After uploading the necessary certs, everything was working as expected.  Hope this answer helps someone in need in the future.  Thanks.